# How can I keep WWW::Mechanize from following redirects?

Tags: perl, redirect, mechanize

I have a Perl script that uses [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) to read from a file and perform some automated tasks on a website.  However, the website uses a 302 redirect after every time I request a certain page.  I don't want to be redirected (the page that it redirects to takes too long to respond); I just want to loop through the file and call the first link over and over.  I can't figure out how to make WWW::Mechanize NOT follow redirects.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`WWW::Mechanize`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize) is a subclass of [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::UserAgent). So you can use any [`LWP::UserAgent`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::UserAgent) methods.

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->requests_redirectable([]);
```

Answer (score 5):

WWW::Mechanize is a subclass of LWP::UserAgent; you can set the max_redirect or requests_redirectable options in the constructor as you would with LWP::UserAgent.

Comment: I've tried setting the max_redirect to 0, but it didn't effect it.

Comment: If indeed max_redirect is not affecting whether or not LWP and Mech doesn't follow redirects, then that is a bug that should be reported.

Answer (score 4):

You can use $agent->max_redirect( 0 );, like in this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $agent = WWW::Mechanize->new( 'autocheck' => 1, 'onerror' => undef, );
$agent->max_redirect( 0 );
$agent->get('http://www.depesz.com/test/redirect');
printf("Got HTTP/%s from %s.\n", $agent->response->code, $agent->uri);

$agent->max_redirect( 1 );
$agent->get('http://www.depesz.com/test/redirect');
printf("Got HTTP/%s from %s.\n", $agent->response->code, $agent->uri);
```

When running it prints:

```
Got HTTP/302 from http://www.depesz.com/test/redirect.
Got HTTP/200 from http://www.depesz.com/.
```

So, with max_redirect(0) - it clearly doesn't follow redirects.

Comment: Oddly enough, changing the max_redirect to 0 didn't work for me (I suspect it's a bug elsewhere in my code with that indirect effect since it SHOULD work), but changing requests_redirectable did work.

Comment: On another note...I use your depesz.com website all the time.  Great resource for Postgres.